# Why Java Files.createFile with permissions doesn't work correctly?

Tags: java, linux, file-permissions

I need to ceate file and set permissions(-rwxrw-r) to it, the permission of parent dir is (drwxrwxr--). The problem is that the write permission is 
not set in created files. The user that ran this application is the owner of the parent dir.

Below is my test class that present the same problem. When I run this program, the permissions of generated file is (-rwxr--r--) though the class set permissions (-rwxrw-rw-). Why the write permission is not set 
and I don't see any exception?

Any idea?

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute;
import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFileAttributes;
import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermission;
import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermissions;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestPermission{

static String parentDir = "/tmp/test/";

static Set<PosixFilePermission> defaultPosixPermissions = null;
static {
    defaultPosixPermissions = new HashSet<>();
    defaultPosixPermissions.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
    defaultPosixPermissions.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);
    defaultPosixPermissions.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE);
    defaultPosixPermissions.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ);
    defaultPosixPermissions.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_WRITE);
    //Others have read permission so that ftp user who doesn't belong to the group can fetch the file
    defaultPosixPermissions.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_READ);
    defaultPosixPermissions.add(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_WRITE);
}


public static void createFileWithPermission(String fileName) throws IOException{
   // File parentFolder = new File(parentDir);
   // PosixFileAttributes attrs = Files.readAttributes(parentFolder.toPath(), PosixFileAttributes.class);
   // System.out.format("parentfolder permissions: %s %s %s%n",
   //   attrs.owner().getName(),
   //   attrs.group().getName(),
   //   PosixFilePermissions.toString(attrs.permissions()));

   // FileAttribute<Set<PosixFilePermission>> attr =  PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(attrs.permissions());
    FileAttribute<Set<PosixFilePermission>> attr =  PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(defaultPosixPermissions);
    File file = new File(fileName);
    Files.createFile(file.toPath(), attr);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    String fileName = parentDir + "testPermission_" + System.currentTimeMillis();
    createFileWithPermission(fileName);

}

}
```

Comment: btw it's better to use `EnumSet` rather than `HashSet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the reason is that my os has a umask as 0027(u=rwx,g=rx,o=) which means application has no way to 
set permission for others group.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the catch here is

> The check for the existence of the file and the creation of the new
>   file if it does not exist are a single operation that is atomic with
>   respect to all other filesystem activities that might affect the
>   directory.

as mentioned in [Class Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...))

This might be because of the OS operations that happen after a file is being created. The following modification in code should get things work fine:

```
File file = new File(fileName);
Files.createFile(file.toPath(), attr);
Files.setPosixFilePermissions(file.toPath(), defaultPosixPermissions);  //Assure the permissions again after the file is created
```

Comment: Long time ago, but this worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

Files.createFile(file.toPath(), attr);

in the above line instead of using Files.createFile
use file.createNewFile() and if it returns true then the file is created.